# How does SSMS display results while they are still returning?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

With ADO.net I only know how to display results once the entire result set has returned, but SSMS seems to be able to start displaying results while they are still being fetched in many cases.

How does it do that?

Apologies if this question has been asked before... seems like it would have been but I didn't see it.

Comment: In ADO.Net, Readers are streams. You can interact with a result before it is completely streamed to you, you just didn't realize it. (not the voter)

Comment: Ahhh... yeah I feel kind of silly now. I knew that I could use BeginExecuteReader() to allow my application to continue processing as the results were being returned but totally didn't think about the fact that I can immediately access the stream. Thanks! Feel free to post that as an answer for some easy points :)

Comment: Exactly my question, but I am not as smart as you guys. BeginExecuteReader(SomCallback, com) does not block my UI but the callback is only called once, after the query has ended. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jan Sorry I would answer if I had time but you will probably be better off just posting a new question asking how to access the stream.

Comment: Thx, I already got it to work! (and maybe I'll leave an answer later), the problem on my side was the sql command text, it could not give back rows until it was finished executing. -.- ^^

Comment: @Jan Ah yeah, if you do an order by or something like that a lot of times  there's no way for it to give you the first result until it's processed the last.